# Number of all system errors

Tags: c

How can I, using e.g. *errno*, in **C**, obtain the number of all system errors (about 130)? I have no idea at all how I can do this...

I searched for information in man, but it did not give anything

Comment: count all these up? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Comment: Why? I don't think this list is static.

Comment: They're enumerated for you here in [errno.h](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/nico/archive/+/v0.97/include/linux/errno.h). Are you saying you want C code that will return the number of all possible `errno` values?

Comment: How i should do it

Comment: I want a count of all errors on my system. This count is not static.

Comment: If you just want textual info about what a number means there's `perror()`.

Comment: I simply mean the NUMBER of problems, not the error messages etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to know this? `errno` has been around for decades, and afaik there's no function call, `#define`, etc to return this information, meaning nobody else has wanted to know this, leading me to believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you really want to know, a better solution probably involves some grep magic or similar to parse errno.h for the number of error codes defined in it.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to know how many times calls are made that result in an error which sets ```errno```?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you've got all of them in the links below (errno sources):

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h
AFAIK there is no array that contains all of them that you could take the length of.

Answer (score 0):

Perl works:

```
perl -e 'for $i (1..150) {$!=$i; print $i." ".$!."\n";}'  |grep -cv 'Unknown [eE]rror'
131
```

Seems to be about 131 on Linux, and 187 on Cygwin.